# Beget function in JavaScript: The Good Parts

Tags: javascript

I am reading JavaScript: The Good Parts. In the book, a beget function is defined. Its purpose is to create and return a new object, which uses the other object as its prototype. Why does the beget function instantiate a new function instead of an object?

```
if( typeof Object.beget !== 'function' ){
    Object.beget = function(o){
          var F =new Function(){}; // this line, why it cannot be var F = new Object();
          F.prototype = o;
          return new F();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is used to create a new object with its prototype set to an object passed in. A constructor, F, is defined, its prototype is set to the passed in object and then a new instance is returned.

Answer (score 28):

This has everything to do with the `new` keyword. In JavaScript, `new` only works with functions (which are a special type of object).

- If you use `new` on just about any function, you will get an object back.

  ```
  alert(typeof console.log); // function
  var dumb = new console.log();  // dumb is an object
  ```
- The type of object you get back depends on that function's prototype object.

  ```
  alert(typeof console.log.prototype); // object, any new objects created by the new keyword will be of this type.
  alert(typeof Function.prototype); // function, new objects are functions.
  alert(typeof new Function()); // function, see?
  alert(typeof (function(){})); // function, using literal syntax, equivalent
  ```
- You may have noticed from above that `Function` itself is a function. In fact, all of the built-in constructors are functions (Function, Object, Number, Array, etc). Capitalization is just a convention to distinguish how you use a function.

So to get back to your question, the author uses an empty Function object simply because it can be used as a constructor. Objects cannot.
He then changes the constructor's prototype, so that it will return objects of that type.

```
Object.beget = function(o) {
    var F = new Function(); // now F can be used as a constructor. 
    F.prototype = o; // All new objects F creates will be based on o.
    return new F();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

To add on to previous answers and avoid some confusion, this `beget()` function was replaced with `create()` via an [errata](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517748), so different books seem to have different version of the code. The book on Safari Books Online has it printed like this:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Note that it no longer encourages the use of the `new` keyword on line 3.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion,as the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) said

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.
>
> > Syntax
> >
> > > new constructor[([arguments])]
> >
> > Parameters
> >
> > > constructor
> > >
> > > > A function that specifies the type of the object instance.
> > >
> > > arguments
> > >
> > > > A list of values that the constructor will be called with.

So,wo have to use a function to create a new instance.

For example:

```
var list = new Array();
typeof Array;//"function"
```

This Array is not a object,but a constructor function.

Comment: does not answer the question on why Function is used, as opposed to Object.

Comment: as the MDN said:The new operator use a constructor **Function** to create an instance.So we use Function rather than Object.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you can't use () on a generic object nor on anything else that isn't a function. You'll get an error something like "TypeError: F is not a function."

Answer (score 1):

```
      // create a temporary function
      var F =new Function(){};
      // set the prototype of the function to be o
      F.prototype = o;
      // create a new object from the function
      return new F();
```

Because that's how `new` works. new creates a new object and places `F.prototype` in the prototype chain.

`new F() === Object.create(F.prototype)`

Comment: why does new Function() has to be called and not new Object() and assign to F?

Comment: @Felix because how do you inherit from the prototype using `new Object` ?

Answer (score 1):

My books is

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
    Object.beget = function (o) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer is in the book only. The beget method created a new object and that object is used as its prototype.

Below line is used to check if beget method is already used or not !

```
if( typeof Object.beget !== 'function' )
```

And then..
A constructor, **F**, is defined, its prototype is set to the passed in object and then a new instance is returned.